# Creating a subnet with VLSM

Tags: subnet

Now I may be wrong in assuming this question is wrong. But from my understanding, it is impossible to have more than 254 hosts on a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask.

link to question > https://gyazo.com/14939d1fe66ac5afcc3c96343ae146fa

So adding all of the hosts you get 427.. And I am unsure of how this can be done even with VLSM?

I`ve also tried online subnetting calculators to see if it can be done and had no luck. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you read that you need to use a /24 subnet mask? You need to start from 175.10.156.0 and create different subnets for each network, allowing space for the required amount of hosts.